# Regular expression and other validation with MVC 3

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, asp.net-mvc-validation

I need to implement following validations in MVC

**1. Date field**

1. A field can accept only mm/dd/yyyy format and should be in a year
   range between 1753-9999 and other basic checks like Leaf year and
   30, 31 days
2. Sometimes a field can accept a text 'N/A'(not applicable)
3. Also date should be greater than start date.

**2. Numeric field**

1. Should accept valid numbers from 1 to 100 , if decimal 0.1 to 99.99
2. Can accept N/A

**3. Dependency Field**

This field is required only if another field has a value.

**4. Triggers**

1. If this field value is A->B then it should affect other field values
   that are editable.

   ***Is there any library for MVC 3 supports all? Or do i combine
   [Foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) and standard MVC validations? Any suggestion for
   implementing my above needs?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you take advantage of HTML5

for Time

```
 @Html.TextBox("timeFrom", DateTime.Now.AddHours(2).ToString("HH:mm"), new { type = "time", size = 3, step = "1" })
```

for date

```
@Html.TextBox("Mydate", new { required = "required", type="date" })
```

for number

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="100">
@Html.TextBox("number", new {type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="100"})
```

for dependency field you can use system.componentmodel. data annotations

Comment: What if they dont use HTML 5?

Comment: Then use system.componentmodel.dataannotations